# is this possible to deny certain controller actions from certain theme when we use multiple themes in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am currently working on a e-commerce  website project. I have multiple themes to manage.  So I'm asking whether is it possible to deny certain controller actions from certain theme when we use multiple themes in yii2?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking at this the wrong way round. You can't exclude certain actions from the theme; themes are used by view files, so by the time they are used, the action has already been determined. What you can do however is to define the theme to be used, whether for the controller, or for individual actions. Simply place this code in code, adjusting for you themes, in either the `init()` function of your controller, or in the action method, before the view is rendered.

```
$this->getView()->theme = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => '\yii\base\Theme',
    'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic'],
    'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MaheshKVishwanathan please could you accept the answer if it worked for you? Thank you!